# Запрос из двух таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы. Как объединить их запрос в один, чтобы можно было вытягивать данные и с той, и с той таблицы

Первый запрос:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `date`='$date' ORDER BY `total` DESC");
```

И второй запрос:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `match_id`='$id' ORDER BY `id`");
```

Comment: при такой постановке вопроса - никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `match_id` соответствует `id` из таблицы 1:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.date='$date' AND b.match_id=a.id
ORDER BY a.total DESC, b.id
");
```

Comment: Отмечайте пожалуйста что ответ помог, для того что бы другие могли быстро найти.

Comment: Блин искал-искал, а где здесь отметить, что ответ помог?)

Comment: где-то слева от моего ответа, точно не помню :)